# Da para personalizar a classe VideoView do android?

Tags: android

Gostaria de saber se tem como personalizar os controles do `VideoView` usando o `MediaController` ou outra classe que permita eu inflar um layout de um player.

Comment: Vale a pena dar uma olhada no ExoPlayer. É bem mais customizável: https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer

Comment: Android da pra personalizar tudo haha